# Proof of convergence of distribution of order statistics

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, order-statistics

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d with distribution $F$ such that for some $a_n>0$, $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$. $F^n(a_n x +b_n) \to \exp(-(1+\gamma x)^{\frac{-1}{\gamma}}$

Define $X_{1,n} \leq \ldots \leq X_{n,n}$ to be the order statistics, and we want to prove $(\frac{X_{n,n}-b_n}{a_n}, \ldots, \frac{X_{n-k+1,n}-b_n}{a_n})$ converges to $(\frac{E_1^{-\gamma}-1}{\gamma}, \ldots, \frac{(E_1+\ldots+E_{k+1})^{-\gamma}-1}{\gamma})$, where $E_i$ are i.i.d. exponential distributed random variable with parameter $1$.

So far, we have proved that $(X_{n,n}, \ldots, X_{n-k+1, n})$ has the same distribution as $(U(\frac{1}{1-e^{-E_{1,n}}}), \ldots, U(\frac{1}{1-e^{-E_{k,n}}}))$.

And we need to derive the result using the fact that $n(E_{1,n}, \ldots E_{k,n}) \to (E_1, \ldots, E_1+\ldots + E_k)$ and $(E_{1,n}\ldots, E_{k,n}) = (\frac{E_1}{n}, \ldots, \frac{E_1}{n}+\ldots \frac{E_k}{n-k+1})$ in distribution.

But I do not know how to do this step, so help would be appreciated there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The proof is from  Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction by Haan and Ferreira